# ko.mapping: Updating model with subscriptions

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I get error when `ko.mapping` updates my model, which have some **subscriptions**. As soon as subscriptions are removed, everything works like a charm. Any idea how to make it work?

Consider this example ([jsfiddle available](http://jsfiddle.net/y48U2/1/)) - Call to `ko.mapping.fromJS()` in `initModel()` triggers error:

```
var iniData = {
    FirstName: "foo",
    LastName: "bar"
};

var PersonModel = function() {
    this.FirstName = ko.observable("");
    this.LastName = ko.observable("");
    this.FullName = ko.observable("");

    // If you comment out subscribe() calls, everything works fine!
    this.FirstName.subscribe(this.updateFullName);    
    this.LastName.subscribe(this.updateFullName);


    // Update FullName only if it's empty
    this.updateFullName = function(){
            if (!this.FullName()) {
                this.FullName(
                    this.LastName() + 
                            this.FirstName() ? (
                                " " + this.FirstName()
                            ):''
                );
            }

        };
    this.initModel = function(){
        try {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(iniData, {}, this);
        }
        catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateFullName` function should be placed before the two subscriptions you are doing, otherwise this method is **not yet known by the JavaScript interpreter**. Like this:

```
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
    self.LastName = ko.observable("");
    self.FullName = ko.observable("");

    // Update FullName only if it's empty
    self.updateFullName = function(){
            if (!self.FullName()) {
                self.FullName(
                    self.LastName() + 
                            self.FirstName() ? (
                                " " + self.FirstName()
                            ):''
                );
            }

        };

    // If you comment out subscribe() calls, everything works fine!
    self.FirstName.subscribe(self.updateFullName);    
    self.LastName.subscribe(self.updateFullName);
```

Also, I think that in your case you should avoid subscriptions and declare the `FullName` as a computed observable, this is the perfect case in fact. Here's how to do it:

```
self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
self.LastName = ko.observable("");
self.FullName = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.LastName() + (self.FirstName() ? " " + self.FirstName() : "");
};
```

Whenever something changes in `FirstName` or `LastName` the computed `FullName` observable is updated.

---

Edit: I checked your fiddle, the other thing that is wrong is that within the `updateFullName` function, the "this" refers to the context of the method, not the context of your view model. Which explains why the `fullName` property is not found. Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y48U2/2/).

Comment: you got it! certainly i should have been declared the update function before referring to it.

Comment: yes, but also check out my fiddle, you should always declare another variable that references your view model, like "self". Because "this" may not always refer to your view model. See http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html

Comment: indeed using `self` is safer. Another option would be to provide `this` value as 2nd argument for `subscribe`, as in http://jsfiddle.net/y48U2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a computed observable make more sense here? Or does the fullName value has to be editable on it's own?

[Edit] whoops, Jalayn was quicker ;)

Comment: exactly, i want to allow to modify FullName, thus using subscriptions (the code is slightly simplified, because it would stop updating FullName as soon as only one one First/Last names are provided...
But in any case, my question applies to much broader scope: ko.mapping.toJS will fail to update ANY model with subscriptions. I want to know the right way to design it.